# Exception: expected<org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException> but was<java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError>

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit4

Im getting this error:

```
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException> but was<java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError>
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:31)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.messageinterpolation.InterpolationTerm
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateExpression(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateMessage(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolate(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.interpolate(ValidationContext.java:370)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.createConstraintViolation(ValidationContext.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.createConstraintViolations(ValidationContext.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateComposingConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:388)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:369)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:339)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1234)
    at com.yavale.baseProject.test.UsuarioTest.unicidadCampoLogin(UsuarioTest.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:22)
    ... 20 more
```

And this is my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml", "classpath:test-applicationContext.xml" }) 
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="transactionManager",defaultRollback=true)
public class RolTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    RolDAO rolDAO;

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory mySessionFactory;


    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UsuarioTest.class);

    @Test(expected=org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public void unicidadCampoNombre() {

        logger.info("Prueba: Se trata de insertar dos roles con el mismo nombre");

        String nombre = "Administrador";

        Rol rol1 = new Rol(nombre, "descripcion");
        Rol rol2 = new Rol(nombre, "descripcion");

        rolDAO.insert(rol1);
        rolDAO.insert(rol2);

        mySessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();

    }
```

The weird thing about this, is that this used to work. Now, mySessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush(); throws this exception. Another weird thing is that I use the same test with different object and it works well:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml", "classpath:test-applicationContext.xml" }) 
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="transactionManager",defaultRollback=true)
public class PermisoTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    PermisoDAO permisoDAO;

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory mySessionFactory;


    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UsuarioTest.class);

    @Test(expected=org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public void unicidadCampoNombre() {

        logger.info("Prueba: Se trata de insertar dos permisos con el mismo nombre");

        String nombre = "Eliminar";

        Permiso permiso1 = new Permiso(nombre, "descripcion");
        Permiso permiso2 = new Permiso(nombre, "descripcion");

        permisoDAO.insert(permiso1);
        permisoDAO.insert(permiso2);

        mySessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();

    }
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have encountered the problem. It was an hibernate constraint that was complaining but the exception didnt show in the test class...

Comment: i have the same problem can you give more detail? in my mapping i have something like this @Table(name = "feedbacks",uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"user_id","client_id"})})

Comment: Downvote because this answer doesn't provide a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 9):

I have also run into this problem when updating from hibernate-validator 4.something to 5.0.1.Final. Apparently, this version of hibernate-validator (and maybe some other hibernate jars) is missing some dependencies, namely el-api and el-ri. I have solved the problem by adding these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
  <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

That seems to me the cleanest way to fix this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue with hibernate 5.0.3, and I tried other people's solution, but the only thing needed in the end for me was:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your classpath and make sure the `InterpolationTerm` class is there.  It's throwing a `ClassDefNotFound` exception when it's trying to run the unit test.  It's probably a missing Hibernate .jar file.

Comment: I dont get it, whats InterpolationTerm class?? Thats not mine. The classpath you mean the file .classpath?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, what helped for me was adding the following dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Maybe this helps somebody.